# Avoid static member "declared weak after being used" error

Tags: c++, gcc

Using the [OpenCL C++ Wrapper 1.2.7](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/api/1.2/cl.hpp) under GCC 5.1.0 gives the error

```
/usr/include/CL/cl.hpp:2442:29: error: cl::Context::default_initialized_ declared weak after being used
     static std::atomic<int> default_initialized_;
```

this is a code listing of the corresponding location:

```
class Context 
    : public detail::Wrapper<cl_context>
{
private:

#ifdef CL_HPP_CPP11_ATOMICS_SUPPORTED 
    static std::atomic<int> default_initialized_; // <- line 2442
#else // !CL_HPP_CPP11_ATOMICS_SUPPORTED
    static volatile int default_initialized_;
#endif // !CL_HPP_CPP11_ATOMICS_SUPPORTED
```

I was only able to find this error message in some patches to GCC and its [source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/837d3ea8155d9e5b75ddcf5fa8f14dac7848eda0/gcc/varasm.c#L5355) and no explanation what it means and how to avoid it.

I think this is referring to a weak symbol <strike>but the error seems to be designed for functions which does not make sense in this context</strike>(based on the old error message "declared inline after being called").

For me this boils down to the following questions:

Who is the culprit? Me, the OpenCL wrapper or GCC?

and

How do I avoid this error?

### MWE

```
#include <CL/cl.hpp>    
int main() {}
```

While creating this example I noticed that the error only occurs when using the undefined behavior sanitizer (`-fsanitize=undefined`).

The problem occurs at another member when using pre C++11 but the error message stays the same.

### Additional Context

I browsed the code of `cl.hpp` and found the likely source of the error.

Both `cl::Context` and `cl::CommandQueue` start with

```
private:
#ifdef CL_HPP_CPP11_ATOMICS_SUPPORTED
    static std::atomic<int> default_initialized_;
#else // !CL_HPP_CPP11_ATOMICS_SUPPORTED
    static volatile int default_initialized_;
#endif // !CL_HPP_CPP11_ATOMICS_SUPPORTED
    static CommandQueue default_;
    static volatile cl_int default_error_;
```

and later have e.g.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#ifdef CL_HPP_CPP11_ATOMICS_SUPPORTED
__declspec(selectany) std::atomic<int> Context::default_initialized_;
#else // !CL_HPP_CPP11_ATOMICS_SUPPORTED
__declspec(selectany) volatile int Context::default_initialized_ = __DEFAULT_NOT_INITIALIZED;
#endif // !CL_HPP_CPP11_ATOMICS_SUPPORTED
__declspec(selectany) Context Context::default_;
__declspec(selectany) volatile cl_int Context::default_error_ = CL_SUCCESS;
#else // !_WIN32
#ifdef CL_HPP_CPP11_ATOMICS_SUPPORTED
__attribute__((weak)) std::atomic<int> Context::default_initialized_;
#else // !CL_HPP_CPP11_ATOMICS_SUPPORTED
__attribute__((weak)) volatile int Context::default_initialized_ = __DEFAULT_NOT_INITIALIZED;
#endif // !CL_HPP_CPP11_ATOMICS_SUPPORTED
__attribute__((weak)) Context Context::default_;
__attribute__((weak)) volatile cl_int Context::default_error_ = CL_SUCCESS;
#endif // !_WIN32
```

Obviously, the weak attribute is added at the definition after the declaration which did not have this attribute.

Thus, my question now is: Is this a shortcoming of the library code or is the UB sanitizer too sensitive?

Comment: Your sample appears incomplete, after all the variable does not appear to be used. If you cannot re-create the issue (on a smaller sample) it makes the question much more difficult to deal with. From the warning you give, apparently something in the code is attempting to change the visibility of the variable after it has already been used, without seeing where it's used and where the visibility change is, this is a puzzle question.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: You are right. I added a MWE.

Comment: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP/issues/17